# How to use xcode's Fix and Continue debugging feature?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I have not find any tutorial about using xcode's "Fix and Continue feature". If someone knows how to use this please let me know. I would like to use this feature in iOs Apps. Does some knows a way to use this. Whenever I use this I got error "classname.m dylib" not found.

Here is a screen-shot when using fix and continue feature for iPhone apps.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Second result from just typing 'xcode fix and continue' into the search field on google gives http://thurly.net/14ty

This shows (albeit following a long previous tutorial) how fix and continue works.

Comment: Second result from just typing 'xcode fix and continue' in Google is this very Stack Overflow question at the time of this writing :-)